# Phpstorm Composer Class Renamed

Tags: php, phpstorm

Throughout our project, we currently have:

```
use Twig_Environment;
// then later in the file:
Twig_Environment $twig
```

Twig updated their class namespaces, so that these need to now be:

```
use Twig\Environment;
// then later in the file:
Environment $tw
```

Is there refactoring functionality in Phpstorm that will handle this for us? Find/Replace isn't ideal here, due to type hinting, comments, etc.

Comment: How about `use Twig\Environment as Twig_Environment`, and keep using that?

Answer (score 5):

You could simply [alias the class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) by replacing:

```
use Twig_Environment;
```

with:

```
use Twig\Environment as Twig_Environment;
```

This will allow you to continue using `Twig_Environment` everywhere else in the file.

To do so, you could use PHPStorm's find and replace feature (which should be safe):

### Find (with Regex enabled)

```
^\s*use\s+Twig_Environment\s*;
```

### Replace

```
use Twig\\Environment as Twig_Environment;
```

In any case, and especially if you're not using any VCS, you should backup your code beforehand and make sure it works on a few individual files first.